# Convert varchar to integer

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a price field. This price field was defined as varchar. The Values is someting like 123,45. I need to convert this varchar field to integer in all records. How i can resolve this?

Comment: Why integer? if that's supposed to be `123.45`, the you'd lose the `.45`

Comment: i need to change to integer field because i need to create some reports but the program just use integer fields.

Comment: so what should the integer value be, then? `123`? `12345`?

Comment: 123.45 with 2 decimal

Comment: `update yourtable set newfield = cast(Replace(oldfield, ",", "") as int) / 100` would be one quick way.

Comment: that give me the following error: 16:14:23 update produtos_vendidos set preis = cast(Replace(preço, ",", ""), int) / 100 Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' int) / 100' at line 1 0.172 sec

Answer (score 2):

If it is all within mySQL that you are doing your conversions, CAST is your friend.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

If you are doing it outside of mysql, virtually all languages have cast functions that should be able to take an input as a string and attempt to convert it to a desired value - for example, c# might use int.Parse(string);

Comment: I think the best way would be to create a new integer field. Now i need to know how i can store the price value (varchar field) to this new integer field.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the cast method or alter the table

```
ALTER TABLE yrtable ALTER COLUMN `price` DECIMAL (10,2);
```

Comment: ALTER TABLE produtos_vendidos ALTER COLUMN preço DECIMAL (10,2); this give me an error

Comment: You will need to make sure that all of your values in that column are able to be numbers.  Also if the column is the primary key, you may need to remove that before altering the type and then resetting the primary key on that column.

Comment: try this instead using the MODIFY keyword. ALTER TABLE yrtable MODIFY price DECIMAL (10,2);

Comment: 16:23:18 ALTER TABLE produtos_vendidos MODIFY preço DECIMAL (10,2) Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '1500,00' 0.266 sec

Comment: It may not like the ',' in the varchar values.  You may need to do an update on the table to replace (via a regex expression) that ',' with a '.' and then you should be able to do the alter table.

Answer (score 0):

This worked better for me. It's from the documentation.

```
ALTER TABLE yrtable CHANGE columnname columnnameagain BIGINT NOT NULL;
```